# VS2010 standard system include files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

My PC has `Windows 2008 Server R2 64bit`, and `VS2010 Ultimate`, originally setup for `C# & VB`  with VS2010 SP1. I just added `VC++ (only x64 option not Itanium)`.  I can not find the standard include files like:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A or v7.0A`.  I did not see any options within the setup/repair for x86, assumed it was the default.  What am I doing wrong?

Update1: Should have mentioned, at one time had VS2010 C++ Express installed. Before posting I tried several things:

- Completely uninstalled C++ Express
- Ran VS2010 Ultimate REPAIR multiple times.
- Completely unstalled VS2010 Ultimate, then re-installed VS2010 Ultimate. Still have same problem.

Update2: According to other SO related posts, the standard files should be in directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include.  I only have these

```
   06/22/2014  11:59 PM    <DIR>          .
   06/22/2014  11:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
   01/18/2011  10:02 PM            11,428 ammintrin.h
   08/31/2009  02:35 AM             2,431 omp.h
   08/31/2009  02:34 AM               527 pgobootrun.h
   08/31/2009  02:36 AM            14,733 srv.h
   08/31/2009  02:06 AM            29,082 wmiatlprov.h
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is definitely broken. This is the most likely reason. Try reinstalling VS. Depending on the size and type of corruption this may work and may not work.

Other less likely case is the option below. Check it.

[image]

On my system in the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include` there are 220 files. You can try to put proper include files into similar directory (10.0 instead of 11.0) on your computer. Difference between versions is not big from this point of view.

Comment: Should have mentioned, at one time had VS2010 C++ Express installed.   Before posting had completely uninstalled C++ Express and Ultimate, then re-installed VS2010 Ultimate.  Still have same problem.

Comment: MS products are not perfect on uninstalling/reinstalling. Unfortunately you can only prey. Sometimes it really works.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall VS2010 Ultimate , it's the safest way to get it done, and it won't take your long time...